# php json decode - get a value

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to extract a specific value from json content . Here it is link with the json code http://www.ebayclassifieds.com/m/AreaSearch?jsoncallback=json&lat=41.1131514&lng=-74.0437521 As you may see the the code displayed is

```
json({items:[{url:"http://fairfield.ebayclassifieds.com/",name:"Fairfield"},{url:"http://newyork.ebayclassifieds.com/",name:"New York City"}],error:null});
```

I need to extract the first url which in this case is "http://fairfield.ebayclassifieds.com/" and its name value which is "Fairfield" , I could do it with regex but I would prefer to use json_decode. Unfortunately when I try to decode it doesn't work

```
$json  = getContent("http://www.ebayclassifieds.com/m/AreaSearch?jsoncallback=json&lat=41.1131514&lng=-74.0437521");
$test = json_decode($json, true);
```

Comment: The problem is, that this is not valid JSON. The "keys" have also to be inside quotes (i.e. `{"items":[{"url":"http://fairfield.ebayclassifieds.com/",name:"Fairfield"}...` I played a little but the `json_decode` function generates a `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX` error because of the faulty quotes.

Comment: Just realised this too, and updated answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 2):

As danp already said, the returned JSON is enclosed in a function call (specified by `jsoncallback=json`). You cannot get rid of this totally but, just using `AreaSearch?jsoncallback=&lat=41.1131514&lng=-74.0437521` removes at least the `json` at the beginning of the string and you can get rid of the brackets by:

```
$json = trim(trim($json), "();");
```

with gives:

```
{items:[{url:"http://fairfield.ebayclassifieds.com/",name:"Fairfield"},{url:"http://newyork.ebayclassifieds.com/",name:"New York City"}],error:null}
```

Unfortunately, the JSON string is not valid. The keys (`items`, `url`, ...) have to be enclosed in quotes `"`. You can easily check that you get a syntax error with [`json_last_error()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) (error code `4`, `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX`).

**Update:**

According to this question: [**Invalid JSON parsing using PHP**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575198/invalid-json-parsing-using-php) , you can make the JSON string valid with:

```
$json = preg_replace('/(\w+):/i', '"\1":', $json);
```

This encloses the keys in quotes.

---

If the string *would* be valid, then you could generate an array via:

```
$a = json_decode($json, true);
```

which would give you:

```
Array
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [url] => http://fairfield.ebayclassifieds.com/
                    [name] => Fairfield
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [url] => http://newyork.ebayclassifieds.com/
                    [name] => New York City
                )
        )
    [error] => 
)
```

So you could get the first URL and name via `$a['items'][0]['url']` and `$a['items'][0]['name']` resp.

---

**But I repeat, the JSON you get as response is *not valid* and you cannot parse it with `json_decode()` in its original form.**

Comment: is there any way to make use of the current "invalid json" ? basically that's how I'm getting it from ebayclassifieds so I cannot change the way is displayed because I don't own ebayclassifieds site :)

Comment: Now I have    $test = '({items:[{url:"http://fairfield.ebayclassifieds.com/",name:"Fairfield"},{url:"http://newyork.ebayclassifieds.com/",name:"New York City"}],error:null});';
    $test = trim(trim($test), "();");
   $test = preg_replace('/(\w+):/i', '"\1":', $test);


    $js = json_decode($test, true);
echo " the js is $js";
but is not working :(

Comment: @Michael : Well, do `echo $test` after the replacement and look whether it is valid and check what `json_last_error()` gives you. BTW. `echo " the js is $js";` will not work anyway, because `$js` will contain an array, not a string. You have to extract the information like I showed you in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its not valid JSON. The keys should be wrapped inside quotes.

You can validate your json using the excellent [JSON Lint](http://www.jsonlint.com/) site.

This is a valid version of the data returned:

```
 {
"items": [
    {
        "url": "http://fairfield.ebayclassifieds.com/",
        "name": "Fairfield"
    },
    {
        "url": "http://newyork.ebayclassifieds.com/",
        "name": "New York City"
    }
],
 "error": "null"
}
```

Comment: I tried    $test = '{items:[{url:"http://fairfield.ebayclassifieds.com/",name:"Fairfield"},{url:"http://newyork.ebayclassifieds.com/",name:"New York City"}],error:null}';
    $js = json_decode($test, true);
echo " the js is $js";
 and is not working either

Comment: Updated answer, its not valid, sorry :)