# Get a specific value in JSON

Tags: php, json

I'm wondering how do i access the 3rd `"value"` using PHP in the following:

```
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "-",
         "name": "-",
         "period": "-",
         "values": [
            {
               "value": 0,
               "end_time": "2011-10-08T07:00:00+0000"
            },
            {
               "value": 0,
               "end_time": "2011-10-09T07:00:00+0000"
            },
            {
               "value": 0,
               "end_time": "2011-10-10T07:00:00+0000"
            }
         ]
```

As for now I'm trying to do something with:

```
$results = json_decode(curl_exec ($curl));
```

But then I'm stuck because there are 3 `"value"` inside of `"values"` and to tell you the truth I'm pretty confused..

Comment: What about `$results->data->values[2]` (object property, array)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076659/php-json-decode-get-a-value

Comment: use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` to see what the decoded array/object looks like. You should be able to work out how to access variables in it from that.

Comment: @Spudley - Thank you buddy, people here acting more like Supervisors than programmers (except you of course).

Comment: @Ricardo That's because no one likes reinventing a wheel....

Answer (score 0):

this code is just for your understanding you can get the better idea from this.

```
<?php

$json = '[{"id": "-","name": "-","period": "-","values": [{"value": 0,"end_time": "2011-10-08T07:00:00+0000"},{"value": 0,"end_time": "2011-10-09T07:00:00+0000"},{"value": 0,"end_time": "2011-10-10T07:00:00+0000"}]}]';

$jasondata =json_decode($json,true);

echo $jasondata[0]['values'][2]['value']; exit;

echo "<pre>"; print_r($jasondata); exit;
?>
```