# php json_decode fails without quotes on key

Tags: php, json

I have json data represented like this

```
{key:"value"}
```

(no quotes arround key...)

I want to translate it to an associative array.

PHP's **json_decode** returns null

How can I add the quotes around the key?? 
thanks...

Comment: There is not built in function but like said adam looks from where you are getting your JSON to send it properly

Comment: It's not uncommon for JSON to come across this way, unfortunately.  Google does it... http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1%20USD=?CAD

Comment: Your link returns a 404 @Laizer and the JSON listed here is *not valid*.

Comment: See this answer for a good solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61386431/250775

Answer (score 15):

You can either fix the JSON at the source so that it returns a valid JSON structure, or you can manually add quotes around the keys.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575198/invalid-json-parsing-using-php/1575315#1575315) to a similar question has an example of how to do that:

```
function my_json_decode($s) {
    $s = str_replace(
        array('"',  "'"),
        array('\"', '"'),
        $s
    );
    $s = preg_replace('/(\w+):/i', '"\1":', $s);
    return json_decode(sprintf('{%s}', $s));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. But I had to remove sprintf('{%s}', $s) and had to use just $s as the argument for json_decode function.

Comment: Excellent Solution. I am not sure why Manjula didnt ACCEPT this as the correct answer yet... over 2 years later...

Comment: @holden321 It's replacing them with keys wrapped in quotes, that's what `$s = preg_replace('/(\w+):/i', '"\1":', $s);` is doing.

Comment: Not a valid solution! Try setting a key or "value" to a url or something with a colon in it. This will fail. eg {key:"va:lue"}

Comment: preg_replace('/(\n[\s||\t]*)(\w+):[\s||\t]/i', '$1"$2":', $json);

Comment: I think you should do a `stripslashes()` before doing `json_decode()`. Although this defined custom function handles most situations, this is not a complete solution as @KXL mentioned.

Comment: If keys are followed by white space, they are missed by this code. Also, the first replace is bad: why replace double quotes with single quotes? If anything this will break JSON syntax even more. And the replacement `array('\"', '"')` is useless: it is a null-operation since both arguments are the same string.

Comment: simply does not add any quote to my json..why is this even voted so much

Comment: The regex part can be approved like this:

`$s = preg_replace('/([{,]\s*)(\w+):/is', '\1"\2":', $s);`

That would ensure unquoted keys have a { or a , in front of them with any amount of whitespace. This is still an imperfect solution, as it might trip over a value containing either of these.

Answer (score 11):

If you can't turn that into valid JSON at the source, then you can use [`Services_JSON`](http://pear.php.net/package/Services_JSON/redirected) from PEAR to parse it, since adding quotes around the key is a non-trivial error-prone process.

`Services_JSON` will correctly parse the invalid key string.

Example:

```
$json = new Services_JSON();
var_dump($json->decode('{key:"value"}'));
```

Output:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["key"]=>
  string(5) "value"
}
```

Comment: thanks, exactly what i was looking for, and still works in modern versions of PHP after all these years (tested on 7.3) - btw if you want arrays instead of objects then construct it as `$json_decoder = new Services_JSON(SERVICES_JSON_IN_ARR | SERVICES_JSON_LOOSE_TYPE);`

Answer (score 8):

To avoid that double quotes are inserted in places where they shouldn't, you should skip those quoted strings in this manipulation.

For instance, if you have this JavaScript object literal in a string:

```
{
   dt:"2016-10-22T09:13:20",
   "x:y":false
}
```

... then care must be taken not to have `22T09:` change into `"22T09":`. Also the already quoted key, `"x:y"` should stay unaltered.

You could use this regular expression for achieving that:

```
preg_replace('/("(.*?)"|(\w+))(\s*:\s*(".*?"|.))/s', '"$2$3"$4', $text);
```

#### Other issues

JavaScript object literals allow numeric constants with left-padded zeroes, like `001`, and/or with the unary `+` sign, which are neither allowed in JSON. To remove those offending characters also, you could use this extended version:

```
preg_replace('/("(.*?)"|(\w+))(\s*:\s*)\+?(0+(?=\d))?(".*?"|.)/s', '"$2$3"$4$6', $text);
```

Answer (score 4):

## DON'T USE REGEX.

REGEX is totally not recommended for such cases, don't use that for parsing such data. If you have a simple goals and want to avoid the stable `PEAR package`, then you might try `JSON-php` library (but no-longer maintained).

1) Get `JSON.phps` file from [here](http://mike.teczno.com/JSON/) and rename to `.php` and replace constructor function names to `__construct`.

2) usage:

```
$content = '{myKey:"valueeeee"}';

include(__DIR__.'/JSON.php'); 
$this->json = new Services_JSON( SERVICES_JSON_LOOSE_TYPE );  // to return objects instead of Associative array, remove the argument
var_dump( $this->json->decode($content)  );
```

Comment: how to add this to laravel controller?

Comment: This worked perfectly and decoded the broken JSON into the correct array. I was then able to call json_encode to correctly encode it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Please do not use regexps to do this! JSON grammar cannot be correctly parsed this way by definition. You will open yourself to a ton of future bugs.

I recommend using a YAML parser, because YAML is a superset of JSON and allows unquoted literals at the same time.

[Symfony YAML component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml.html) works great.

There will be a performance penalty in comparison to `json_decode` which is implemented natively.

Answer (score 3):

```php
$results = \Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml::parse("{a: d, b: 'c', e: [a, 3]}");
```

You probably can only use that lib without having to use the whole Symfony package : https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/yaml

Comment: Thanks, this is what I've been looking for. And to make it work, you have to make sure that there is a space after the colon. E.g. "{a:d, b:'c'}" -> this won't work. "{a: d, b: 'c'}" -> this will work.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](http://php.net/json_decode) (see Example #3 - 'common mistakes using json_decode'), keys  must be enclosed in double quotes.

Where are you getting the JSON data?

Comment: .. thus you have no "json data" - at least no valid ones.

Comment: This would have been more appropriate as a comment, as it does not attempt to answer the question "How can I add the quotes..."

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, using regex replace '/\s(\w+)\s/i'

```
$json =  file_get_contents("php://input"); // or whatever json data
$json = preg_replace('/\s(\w+)\s/i', '"$1"', $json);
$json = json_decode($json, true);
```

Comment: This will add double quotes inside values, while it will miss the keys if they have no white space around them: `{s:"this is my string", flag: false , n: 9 }` will become `{s:"this"is"my string", flag:"false", n:"9"}`.

Comment: just add the : in the regex, it should be actually voted as a good answer

Answer (score 0):

I tested many of the solutions proposed here and nothing worked correctly.

- @Intelekshual does not work with more "complex" cases.

```php
$json='{hello:{a:2,b:3},world:[1,2,3,"aaa","bbbb"]}';

var_dump(my_json_decode($json)); // returns null

function my_json_decode($s) {
    $s = str_replace(
        array('"',  "'"),
        array('\"', '"'),
        $s
    );
    $s = preg_replace('/(\w+):/i', '"\1":', $s);
    return json_decode(sprintf('{%s}', $s));
}
```

- @rid and @T.Todua the library does not work because the code targets PHP 4.x/5.x and it has many deprecated features.

So I created an adaptation of Services_JSON (PECL) and updated the code to PHP 7.2 and higher (including PHP 8.1). It works with Composer and it doesn't have any other dependency.

https://github.com/EFTEC/Services_JSON

Or you could copy and paste the code from here:

https://github.com/EFTEC/Services_JSON/blob/main/src/Services_JSON.php