# format json response into parent and child

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, dynamic-arrays

Hi I have got a response from a query.The response is like:

```
{ data: [
       {
       parent: "summer",
       image: "template/assets/x354.jpg",
       productName: "United Colors of Benetton"    },   {   parent: "autumn",   image: "template/assets/x354.jpg",   productName: "United
   Colors of Benetton" }, { parent: "summer", image:
   "template/assets/x354.jpg", productName: "Puma Running Shoes" } ] }
```

Basically I want a function in php to format this response.The
   identical parent in the response in this case it is "summer",the data
   of the summer should print under it.i.e summer should be the parent
   of the data.The desired response is:

```
{ data: [
       {
        parent: "autumn",
        image: "template/assets/x354.jpg", productName: "United Colors of Benetton" }, { parent: "summer" [{ image:
   "template/assets/x354.jpg", productName: "United Colors of Benetton"
   }, { image: "template/assets/x354.jpg", productName: "Puma Running
   Shoes" } ] }

   ] }
```

Comment: Please, take 2 minutes and run your JSON through a formatter. This is like looking at bad expressionistic painting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query response you posted does not seem to be valid JSON because the object properties are not quoted strings, you'll have to care about that to be able to parse the JSON string with `json_decode()`. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6941739/846987 for example.)

This should generate your desired output:

```php
<?php

$json = <<<EOT
{
    "data": [
        {
            "parent": "summer",
            "image": "template\/assets\/x354.jpg",
            "productName": "United Colors of Benetton"
        },
        {
            "parent": "autumn",
            "image": "template\/assets\/x354.jpg",
            "productName": "United Colors of Benetton"
        },
        {
            "parent": "summer",
            "image": "template\/assets\/x354.jpg",
            "productName": "Puma Running Shoes"
        }
    ]
}
EOT;
$jsonObject = json_decode($json);

$categories = array();
foreach($jsonObject->data as $element) {
  if ( ! isset($categories[$element->parent])) {
    $categories[$element->parent] = array();
  }
  $categories[$element->parent][] = $element;
  unset($element->parent);
}

echo '<pre>' . json_encode($categories, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: I tried changing the code which you have posted here to get the response like: