# Convert Json Javascript format to PHP readable format

Tags: javascript, php, json, curl

I have bunch of json files to read through and store some information to db using PHP.

The problem is these json keys are without quotes like:

`[{f:{v:11,ib:5,gh:"res",bfr:7,ju:7,ugy:8,ki:"y"...`

PHP doesn't recognize it as json. However, if I take this json file and run it in a browser with javascript function "JSON.stringify" the data is formatted with quotes which can be used in PHP.

So I wrote a script to parse these files using javascript and then post it to PHP script to write it to the server. Works well in the browser BUT I cannot automate this as curl does not run javascript!!!

Is there anyway to convert json format (without quotes) to PHP readable format? I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941642/php-json-decode-fails-without-quotes-on-key) suggestion... regex option did not work and I do not know how to work with PEAR, even though my server has PEAR Version: 1.10.1 and PHP Version: 5.4.45

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40326949/5459839) I added to the question you referred to. It should solve your case as well.

Comment: Thank you for the regex that you posted for my question, it works well BUT integers with leading zero like this: "code":012345 will not json_decode in PHP.

Can the regex be modified to make integers leading with zero to be quoted?

Comment: I see what you mean, but it they are integers in the JavaScript notation, they should also be integers in the JSON to be consistent, so I would suggest a solution where the non-necessary pre-padded zeroes are removed. If you find that acceptable, I will add such a solution, but otherwise (if it needs to be quoted), I suggest you ask a new question, because such is very specific behaviour that does not fit the context of my answer.

Comment: Sure non-necessary pre-padded zeroes can be removed.

Comment: OK, I added a regex for that as well in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40326949/5459839).

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution to your problem. Yeah it is regex but it works.

```
$text = preg_replace(["/\\\\'/", '/("(.*?)"|(\w+))(\s*:\s*(".*?"|.))/s'], ["'", '"$2$3"$4'], $text);
$text = json_decode($text);
```

$text - is the bad formatted json

For the last comment this should work:

```
$text = preg_replace(["/\\\\'/", '/("(.*?)"|(\w+))(\s*:\s*(".*?"|.))/s', '/((:\s*)(0\d+))/'], ["'", '"$2$3"$4', '$2"$3"'], $text);
```

Comment: Unreliable! Changes this `"2013-01-05T08:02:01"` to `"2013-01-"05T08":"02":01"`

Comment: What about my updated answer?

Comment: Alright regex guru - it works! BUT I had to `$text = str_replace("\'", "'", $text);`  before json_decode. If it can be rolled into regex, it would be perfect one line solution.

Comment: I ran across another glitch when the values had `:` like `"smile please:)"` which becomes `"smile "please":)"`. trincot regex worked. This is the working code: `$text = preg_replace(["/\\\\'/", '/("(.*?)"|(\w+))(\s*:\s*(".*?"|.))/s'], ["'", '"$2$3"$4'], $text);`

Comment: Another gotcha - integers with leading zero like this: "code":012345 will not json_decode in PHP. Can the regex be modified to make integers leading with zero to be quoted?

Comment: Check my updated answer