# PHP add quotes to array for json_decode

Tags: php, json, preg-split

I'm looking to json_decode a string, but running into a problem with the array elements not having quotes.

**JSON**

```
{"Status":"DISPUTED","GUID":[]}
{"Status":"CONFIRMED","GUID":[G018712, G017623]}
```

**PHP**

```
$json = '{"Status":"CONFIRMED","GUID":[G018712,G017623]}';
$a = json_decode($json, true);
print $a['Status'];
```

**Results**

The php print above won't display anything because there are letters mixed in with the numerics within the array and the json_decode doesn't like it. How would you add strings to each array item, so that json_decode will work?

Comment: That service is not providing valid JSON.

Comment: this is invalid JSON... test it on [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com)

Comment: I think the OP is aware it's invalid. The OP is looking for a way to handle this particular case.

Comment: This was answered here (I believe it answers your question): [Invalid JSON parsing using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575198/invalid-json-parsing-using-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `json` is invalid. It should be -

```
$json = '{"Status":"CONFIRMED","GUID":["G018712","G017623"]}';
```

or

```
$json = '{Status:"CONFIRMED",GUID:["G018712","G017623"]}';
```

---

You can easily fix it using-

```
$json = preg_replace('/(?<!")(?<!\w)(\w+)(?!")(?!\w)/', '"$1"', $json);
```

---

Full example

```
$json = '{"Status":"CONFIRMED","GUID":[G018712,G017623]}{"Status":"CONFIRMED","GUID":[018712,a017623]}';
// fix json
$json = preg_replace('/(?<!")(?<!\w)(\w+)(?!")(?!\w)/', '"$1"', $json);
$a = json_decode($json, true);
print $a['Status'];
```