# presumed difference in php versions causing difference in JSON output - quotes around integers

Tags: php, json, laravel, quotes, string-literals

I have a testing server with PHP version 5.5.9, and we have a QA server with PHP version 5.6.16.

I am for the sake of this post using the same code branch on both instances (full disclosure:  it's a Laravel install but I'm not sure this is a Laravel issue)

On the QA server, an API returns JSON with the integers unquoted as follows (this is simplified):

```
{["id":1,"name":"John"],["id":2,"name":"Sam"]}
```

But on my server (the 5.6.16 one), the same exact API call returns:

```
{["id":"1","name":"John"],["id":"2","name":"Sam"]}
```

And, Angular is not liking that and does not parse it.

### It's not the data

The data and tables the data is coming from are exactly alike in structure - I have verified this.

### I don't want to "fix" Angular

Though in theory Angular should handle this(?), I don't want to touch our coding for the front end.

### I want the output to be the same..

Regardless of what Angular is doing, the obvious solution is to have the outputs be exactly equal.

### What do I do?

- I want to avoid upgrading PHP on my server - that might open up more problems
- I am thinking that there is a setting in json_encode() which can be set to change this but I do not know which one.
- Also there may be a setting in laravel itself which could be at least locally changed on my end.  For the record there are well over 100+ `json_encode` calls in the codebase.

Comment: my guess. its how you load the data... and not json_encode()

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390983/php-json-encode-encoding-numbers-as-strings.

Comment: maybe this could help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9881435/4668162

Comment: If the data comes from the database, it could be related to for example the mysql driver used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323146/mysql-integer-field-is-returned-as-string-in-php

Comment: What @jeroen wrote is 100% the problem you're having. One server probably has mysql native driver for PHP while the other one hasn't. Without `mysqlnd` PHP can't interpret data types so it treats them as strings, hence quoted integers. You **should** update your PHP. The other solution is to manually typecast fields - and that can take up so much time.

Comment: Thanks to @jeroen, and also to @Mjh for specifying the PHP upgrade for the driver.  This is the most elegant solution as updating all instances of `json_encode()` would be unreliable and a hack.

Answer (score 1):

Its not an issue in `json_encode()` it is what you are encoding that makes a difference. See this simple example

```
$a = array(
    'id' => 111,
    'astring' => 'test',
    'OhLookItsANumberRecordedAsAString' => '456'
);
$json = json_encode($a);
echo $json;
```

Result

```
{"id":111,
 "astring":"test",
 "OhLookItsANumberRecordedAsAString":"456"
}
```

But if you make sure the integers are integers all is as you expect

```
$a = array(
        'id' => 111,
        'astring' => 'test',
        'OhLookItsANumberRecordedAsAString' => '456',
        'ANumber' => (int)'456'
    );
$json = json_encode($a);
echo $json;
```

Result

```
{"id":111,
 "astring":"test",
 "OhLookItsANumberRecordedAsAString":"456",
 "ANumber":456
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the post here but the actual comments below my OP are actually the most prescient.  This is not helpful from a standpoint of _why_ the condition is happening.  Points for the typecasting though - it would just be hard to update code that way.

Answer (score 0):

As @RiggsFolly it definitely depends on how the source is providing the integer data. If the numbers are quoted from source, json_decoder treats them as a string.

Something you can try: json_encode as a 2nd parameter called $options. Set it to attempt to encode numbers as integers rather than strings.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

[PHP json_encode encoding numbers as strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390983/php-json-encode-encoding-numbers-as-strings)