# PHP json double quotes requirement

Tags: php, json

PHP's JSON decode requires a JSON formatted with field names enclosed in double quotes like:

```
{"foo-bar": 12345, "myName": "Johnnie"}
```

But I have to parse some relatively complex JSON made by a Java application that is formatted with names without double quotes on field names like:

```
{foo-bar: 13456, myName: "Johnnie"}
```

...but more complex. Is there some easy way to fix this or am I screwed?

Comment: Which json parser are you using on the Java side? The correct way would be with the double quotes. If you are using Jackson, it can be configured.

Comment: The requirement you describe is a requirement of JSON, not PHP. The data generated by the Java application simply isn't JSON. It isn't even valid JavaScript syntax (since identifiers can't have hyphens in them).

Comment: I'm not sure which parser is used on the Java side, I just got the incorrectly formatted data. As for hyphens, that's just from the PHP website, I don't think any field names have hyphens in the strings I got. Can PHP parse Javascript in a similar way?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1575315/1301076 it might help to unscrew things if you can't fix it at the source

Comment: Yup, that will do it.

Answer (score 0):

This requirement follows the JSON specification. If you look at the charts at http://json.org/ you will see that an object consists out of  string:value pairs.

[image: JSON object description]

A string is defined to have quotes enclosing Unicode characters.

[image: JSON sring description]

The data you have is not valid JSON.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. I am looking for a solution.

Comment: Fix the data or write your own parser, built-in PHP doesn't provide anything that really helps. Maybe a less restrictive parser exists already? - I don't know.