# How to convert partially invalid JSON to a valid one?

Tags: php, json, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am using php to scrape a webpage and get this string:

```
'[{endTime:"2019-06-05T17:15:00.000+10:00",startTime:"2019-06-05T17:00:00.000+10:00"}]'
```

which is not valid json, the key names are encapsulated ...

I use preg_replace to create valid json:

```
$x = '[{endTime:"2019-06-05T17:15:00.000+10:00",startTime:"2019-06-05T17:00:00.000+10:00"}]'
$j = preg_replace('/(\w+)\s{0,1}:/', '"\1":', $x);
```

and get this value:

```
'[{"endTime":"2019-06-"05T17":"15":00.000+"10":00","startTime":"2019-06-"05T17":"00":00.000+"10":00"}]'
```

but I want this value:

```
'[{"endTime":"2019-06-05T17:15:00.000+10:00","startTime":"2019-06-05T17:00:00.000+10:00"}]'
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid JSON parsing using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575198/invalid-json-parsing-using-php)

Comment: Thanks @KonstantinSvintsov - no that does not solve the question, because I don't have a problem with single/double quotes - it actually points out a problem with that answer

Comment: Find a parser that can parse *Javascript literals*. Don’t try to “fix” arbitrary strings with regexen.

Comment: can you suggest one ?

Comment: My Google search would be as good as yours…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### RegEx 1

Your original expression seems to be find, we would just slightly modify that to:

```
([{,])(\w+)(\s+)?:
```

and it might work, we are adding a left boundary:

```
([{,])
```

and a right boundary:

```
:
```

and our key attribute is in this capturing group:

```
(\w+)
```

---

### RegEx 2

We can expand our first expression to:

```
([{,])(\s+)?(\w+)(\s+)?:
```

in case, we might be having spaces before the key attribute:

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TFZWCR/1)

#### Test 1

```
$re = '/([{,])(\w+)(\s+)?:/m';
$x = '[{endTime:"2019-06-05T17:15:00.000+10:00",startTime:"2019-06-05T17:00:00.000+10:00"}]';
$subst = '$1"$2":';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $x);

echo $result;
```

#### Test 2

```
$re = '/([{,])(\s+)?(\w+)(\s+)?:/m';
$x = '[{endTime:"2019-06-05T17:15:00.000+10:00",startTime:"2019-06-05T17:00:00.000+10:00"}]';
$subst = '$1"$3":';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $x);

echo $result;
```

#### Output

```
[{"endTime":"2019-06-05T17:15:00.000+10:00","startTime":"2019-06-05T17:00:00.000+10:00"}]
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hbSIKD/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: my output to the test is :["{":"2019-06-05T17:15:00.000+10:00"",":"2019-06-05T17:00:00.000+10:00"}]

Answer (score 0):

**use this pattern :**

```regex
([{,])([^:]+):
```

*it will find all texts which are following by `{` or `,`*

**and use this for replacement:**

```
$1"$2":
```

*It will add a doublequote on both sides of your word.*

Comment: this is close, but it's just too greedy, it works on that example, but if the value contains a comma, it's to greedy on the comma - eg value "21 Way street, suburb"

Comment: Your example seems that it is always a dateTime, maybe you should ask your question more clear than this :-)

Comment: I agree - but it was where I was stumbling - thanks for your input