# PHP json_decode - quote formatting

Tags: php, json, regex

I'm trying to decode a json string with `json_decode($str, false)`. But the format is not correct.

```
{mDetailedState:CONNECTED,mExtraInfo:3gnet,mIsAvailable:true}
```

I guess it is because of the quote issue.

For key, I can add the quote back by ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29270169/5737856))

`$json = preg_replace('/([{,])(\s*)([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+?)\s*:/','$1"$3":',$json);`

The result will be

```
{"mDetailedState":CONNECTED,"mExtraInfo":3gnet,"mIsAvailable":true}
```

But, this function cannot add quote back to the value. I am not familiar with regex. Any reference I can refer in order to add the quote back to value or any idea I can convert the json to array easier? Thanks

Comment: How did the data get like this? It's not valid JSON. The correct solution is to fix whatever generated this data so it outputs valid JSON

Comment: @ADyson correct. I'm trying to fix the data, so that it becomes valid JSON

Comment: Yes but my point was that you have to fix it _at source_, when it's being generated. Fixing it reliably after the fact is nearly impossible. Where did you get this data from?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The source is we get the data from device directly. I understand the way it generated does not save correct. It will fix soon. But, I wanna to analyze the data asap, so I need to fix on my side first. Hope you can understnad:)

Comment: ```$new_name = preg_replace('/([:])(\s*)([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+?)\s*,/','$1"$3",',$new_name);``` I'm trying this approach, but seems it cannot add the quote to the last value.

Comment: It's extremely difficult to do this reliably, and almost impossible to cover all cases, so actually if you want it fast, a quicker solution is to go and fix the source of the data. If you can guarantee the data contents never have `"`, `:`, `{`, `}`, `[`, `]` or `,` inside them, then it _might_ be a bit easier to write a routine to sort out the data but it still isn't straightforward, and I don't know if you can guarantee that.

Comment: @ADyson Fix the source will take at least 14 days in order to get the data again. But, fix the value with quote may be 1 day. My current approach is to add back the quote to value. Then recrusively check the value like if int or bool, then stop. If array, will decode that json string again.

Comment: _"Fix the source will take at least 14 days in order to get the data again"_ - So? The source returns data in an invalid format, and should be fixed (or rather shouldn't have been marked as done in the first place). Btw, if it would take at least 14 days to fix the format at the source, wouldn't it take as long to write that code no matter where you add that fix?

Comment: What is `{IDLE=DISCONNECTED,...}` supposed to mean?

Comment: And `toString:[type:MOBILE[LTE],...]` is strange too. You will need to clarify what PHP value you're expecting to get.

Comment: @Olivier  I simplified a bit. Would it be more easier to have a look? Thanks.

Comment: @M.Eriksson lucky, major of fix can be done by hard code. Just the quote issue remains

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you did severely simplify your original question by the time I found a "solution", and your initial payload contained square brackets and equal signs, and without quotes the whole syntax is super brittle, I still made my best to lex and parse the data with a couple of assumptions:

1. Square and curly brackets are assumed to be the same and assume to start a new associative array.
2. Equal signs and colons are assumed to be the same and assume to denote key and value for the associative array.
3. Square and curly brackets that follow a value are assumed to be part of the value and require closing square or curly brackets.

```php
$data = '{mDetailedState:CONNECTED,mExtraInfo:3gnet,mIsAvailable:true,mIsFailover:false,mIsMetered:true,mIsRoaming:false,mNetworkType:0,mReason:connected,mState:CONNECTED,mSubtype:13,mSubtypeName:LTE,mTypeName:MOBILE,CREATOR:android.net.NetworkInfo$1@41bcdce,stateMap:{IDLE=DISCONNECTED,SCANNING=DISCONNECTED,CONNECTING=CONNECTING,AUTHENTICATING=CONNECTING,
OBTAINING_IPADDR=CONNECTING,CONNECTED=CONNECTED,SUSPENDED=SUSPENDED,DISCONNECTING=DISCONNECTING,DISCONNECTED=DISCONNECTED,FAILED=DISCONNECTED,BLOCKED=DISCONNECTED,VERIFYING_POOR_LINK=CONNECTING,CAPTIVE_PORTAL_CHECK=CONNECTING},describeContents:0,getDetailedState:CONNECTED,getExtraInfo:3gnet,getReason:connected,getState:CONNECTED,getSubtype:13,getSubtypeName:LTE,getType:0,getTypeName:MOBILE,isAvailable:true,isConnected:true,isConnectedOrConnecting:true,isFailover:false,isMetered:true,isRoaming:false,toString:[type:MOBILE[LTE],state:CONNECTED/CONNECTED,reason:connected,extra:3gnet,failover:false,available:true,roaming:false,metered:true]}';

$object = null;
$state = [];
$accumulator = '';
$pointer = [];

function set( &$object, $pointer, $value ) {
    if ( empty( $pointer ) ) {
        $object = $value;
        return;
    }

    $point = &$object;
    foreach ( array_slice( $pointer, 0, -1 ) as $key ) {
        $point = &$object[ $key ];
    }
    $point[ end( $pointer ) ] = $value;
}

foreach ( str_split( $data ) as $c ) {
    switch ( $c ):
        case '{':
        case '[':
            if ( end( $state ) === 'new_value' ) {
                if ( $accumulator ) {
                    $accumulator .= $c;
                    array_push( $state, 'new_array' );
                } else {
                    array_pop( $state );
                }
                break;
            }

            set( $object, $pointer, [] );
            array_push( $state, 'new_object' );
            break;
        case '}':
        case ']':
            if ( end( $state ) === 'new_array' ) {
                $accumulator .= $c;
                array_pop( $state );
            }

            if ( end( $state ) === 'new_value' ) {
                set( $object, $pointer, $accumulator );
                $accumulator = '';
                array_pop( $pointer );
                array_pop( $state );
            }

            if ( end( $state ) === 'new_object' ) {
                array_pop( $pointer );
                array_pop( $state );
            }

            break;
        case ':':
        case '=':
            array_push( $pointer, $accumulator );
            $accumulator = '';
            set( $object, $pointer, [] );
            array_push( $state, 'new_value' );
            break;
        case ',':
            if ( end( $state ) === 'new_value' ) {
                set( $object, $pointer, $accumulator );
                $accumulator = '';
                array_pop( $state );
                array_pop( $pointer );
            }
            break;
        default:
            $accumulator .= $c;
            break;
    endswitch;
}

var_dump( $object );
```

```php
array(30) {
  'mDetailedState' =>
  string(9) "CONNECTED"
  'mExtraInfo' =>
  string(5) "3gnet"
  'mIsAvailable' =>
  string(4) "true"
  'mIsFailover' =>
  string(5) "false"
  'mIsMetered' =>
  string(4) "true"
  'mIsRoaming' =>
  string(5) "false"
  'mNetworkType' =>
  string(1) "0"
  'mReason' =>
  string(9) "connected"
  'mState' =>
  string(9) "CONNECTED"
  'mSubtype' =>
  string(2) "13"
  'mSubtypeName' =>
  string(3) "LTE"
  'mTypeName' =>
  string(6) "MOBILE"
  'CREATOR' =>
  string(33) "android.net.NetworkInfo$1@41bcdce"
  'stateMap' =>
  array(13) {
    'IDLE' =>
    string(12) "DISCONNECTED"
    'SCANNING' =>
    string(12) "DISCONNECTED"
    'CONNECTING' =>
    string(10) "CONNECTING"
    'AUTHENTICATING' =>
    string(10) "CONNECTING"
    'OBTAINING_IPADDR' =>
    string(10) "CONNECTING"
    'CONNECTED' =>
    string(9) "CONNECTED"
    'SUSPENDED' =>
    string(9) "SUSPENDED"
    'DISCONNECTING' =>
    string(13) "DISCONNECTING"
    'DISCONNECTED' =>
    string(12) "DISCONNECTED"
    'FAILED' =>
    string(12) "DISCONNECTED"
    'BLOCKED' =>
    string(12) "DISCONNECTED"
    'VERIFYING_POOR_LINK' =>
    string(10) "CONNECTING"
    'CAPTIVE_PORTAL_CHECK' =>
    string(10) "CONNECTING"
  }
  'describeContents' =>
  string(1) "0"
  'getDetailedState' =>
  string(9) "CONNECTED"
  'getExtraInfo' =>
  string(5) "3gnet"
  'getReason' =>
  string(9) "connected"
  'getState' =>
  string(9) "CONNECTED"
  'getSubtype' =>
  string(2) "13"
  'getSubtypeName' =>
  string(3) "LTE"
  'getType' =>
  string(1) "0"
  'getTypeName' =>
  string(6) "MOBILE"
  'isAvailable' =>
  string(4) "true"
  'isConnected' =>
  string(4) "true"
  'isConnectedOrConnecting' =>
  string(4) "true"
  'isFailover' =>
  string(5) "false"
  'isMetered' =>
  string(4) "true"
  'isRoaming' =>
  string(5) "false"
  'toString' =>
  array(8) {
    'type' =>
    string(11) "MOBILE[LTE]"
    'state' =>
    string(19) "CONNECTED/CONNECTED"
    'reason' =>
    string(9) "connected"
    'extra' =>
    string(5) "3gnet"
    'failover' =>
    string(5) "false"
    'available' =>
    string(4) "true"
    'roaming' =>
    string(5) "false"
    'metered' =>
    string(4) "true"
  }
}
```

While this demonstrates a working example, there are edge cases that the data might eventually contain, like extra commas in values, etc. This problem cannot be reliably solved, and is probably too hard to solve using regular expressions even with cleaning up (replacing all = to :, etc.). As you encounter edge cases you'll need to further convolute the state machine and add error checking, tracing and unit testing.

As others have said send properly structured/serialized data from the device. Without a formal grammar this can be made to work on assumptions, which, believe me, will break and the parser will need to be fixed over and over again. But the code above can get you started for the 14 days if you need.

Comment: Thanks for your approach. Will do the data cleaning and restructure for sure. Already inform the team to save a proper json format, so that it does not give the other parties a painful decode. :)